# How to burn image or ISO from a cd/dvd to ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, iso, cd-image

I have an installation disk of Sacred 2 Fallen Angel with serial code and all that but ubuntu 14.04 does not see anything on the disk. I have it mounted under Devices as S2DISC1 but when I click it it's empty.

So I'm wondering if there is a program already on ubuntu that can copy an image or .iso from the cd to my computer and run it from there? I think I used Daemon Tools for that on windows but I never had the problem of not being able to boot a cd there.

Answer (score 0):

When burning an iso file in Ubuntu, you should be able to put the blank disc in, and it will bring up the prompt to select what you want to do. Select cancel and find the iso file. Right click the iso file, and select 'Write to disc'. This will bring up a prompt that lets you write the file to the disc.

Select the disc drive you want to burn to, and select your write speed. If writing the Ubuntu iso to a disc, it's recommended to use the lowest write speed possible. Click 'Burn', and wait for it finish. Once finished, verify that there are multiple files on the disc, and not just a copy of the iso.

Answer (score 0):

There are no real alternatives to Daemon Tools, but these two are probably the best you'll get:


Mountiso - command-line tool: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountIso

 Acetonel - if you're looking for a GUI: https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/acetoneiso/

Answer (score 0):

If you have an ISO file obtained from a CD or DVD, you do not need any extra software to run it on Linux. You can mount it as any other device with this command:

```
mount -o loop -t iso9660 fileName.iso /your/destination/folder
```

You then will be able to run the files on the CD as it was in a real CD unit. Note than in some cases that the CD has copy protection, maybe notes that you do not have an original CD inserted in your computer CD driver.